# Add a .dev command as url in a facebook app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rack-pow

I want to test a facebook login with a ruby on rails app.  I am using pow, so the domain name of my local server is `http://my_app.dev/`. If I put this into the `Site Url` for my facebook app, I get the following error message:

```
This URL contains an invalid domain.
```

If I put in `http://localhost:3000/` it is accepted. How do I use the pow local server.

Comment: Use a domain name without an underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Cbrow's comment, you can create an alias symlink e.g

```
cd ~/.pow
ln -s ~/Projects/my_app fbmyapp
```

You can then enter the domain as `fbmyapp.dev` in your facebook app, then access it on the local machine at `fbmyapp.dev`.